# SharePoint Online: REST API for List, calling Filters and limit the return items

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

I am trying to call REST API for list using below REST API

```
https://myweb.sharepoint.com/teams/sites/subwebs/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?
$top=1
&$orderby=ID
&$select=ID,FName,LName,Title
&$filter=Title eq 'Female'
```

I need $filter should work with number of records limited to $top. The $top works if $filter is not applied.

Well, my list contains the items more than 5000. I received below error message while making GET Request for above URL

```
{
"readyState": 4,
"responseText": "{\"odata.error\":{\"code\":\"-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.\"}}}",
"responseJSON": {
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2147024860, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the `enter code here`administrator."
        }
    }
},
"status": 500,
"statusText": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQueryThrottledException` is thrown since `$filter=Title eq 'Female'` query causes to walk through the whole list and check every row to see if it matches.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx):

> The list view threshold does not apply simply to the number of results
>   returned by your query. Instead, it restricts the numbers of database
>   rows that can be accessed in order to complete execution of the query
>   at the row level in the content database.

That's why `$top` query option is not applicable here.

One option to avoid the issue would be indexing the `Title` field.

Go to `List Settings -> Indexed Columns -> Create a new index  -> select Title as a Primary Column`:

[image]

Once `Title` field is indexed, the following query should succeed:

```
https://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<list title>')/Items?$top=1&$orderby=ID&$select=ID,Title&$filter=Title eq '<value>'
```

Comment: I did the same but still am getting same error. `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$top=1000&$filter= ColumnName eq 'abc'"`. Here `ColumnName` is indexed. And there are more than 5000 records having value "abc" in `ColumnName`. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

I know this may sound very obvious, but the first filter must return 5,000 items or less.
Then you can add other filters. You may not need the $top parameter in this case.
For instance:

```
https://site/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<List Title>')/Items?$filter=<Column Name> eq '<A value that you know returns 5,000 items or less>' and Title eq 'Female'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the filter you have to put ID gt 10 on. ID or another indexed column. I tried it and works here. You have to use one correct value for you, after gt.

Answer (score -1):

```
Promise.all([
rest call # 1 query : queryFilter:"ID lt '3000' and  Title eq '000672'"
rest call # 2 query : queryFilter:"ID gt '2999' and  Title eq '000672'"


.then( arr=> {
        let fullArr = [...a[0],...a[1]]
```