# apply filter to SharePoint social rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-jsom

I am using the following rest api query to get the followed documents of a user in a SharePoint tenant as thus

```
   var followedContentQuery=  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=2)";
```

I need to trim the result to retrieve the top 3 documents only, however, if I use the "top" filter it throws an error

```
  var followedContentQuery=  _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=2)?&top=3";
```

please how can retrieve the top n followed content from this rest api query.

Regards.

Comment: What is the error?  Anything about a threshold limit...?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40362465/sharepoint-online-rest-api-for-list-calling-filters-and-limit-the-return-items